# How can I solve this error in OMNest 5.5.1?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I get the following error:

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "C:/OMNEST-5.5.1/samples/enera/lteAdvanced/enera.exe" (in directory "C:\OMNEST-5.5.1\samples\enera\lte"): CreateProcess error=2, The System cannot find the file.

I already built the project many times. I have tried to make a simplier already given example from omnet just to check if this is working. It is working. But if I copy this example in my Project it also doesn't work, so there is sth wrong with my Project file. But it seems to be correct. I just have one Connection and kept it really really simple. But it doesn't work. I have installed Omnest and inet correctly.

Comment: PS: Th exe.file also exists.:/

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the EXE file cannot find the omnet++ dynamic libraries it tries the load. And the most likely reason is that you are trying to execute the executable from a CMD prompt instead of from the shell provided by the mingwenv.cmd script.

Everything you do in OMNeT++ (including starting the simulations) must be run from the mingwenv shell.